# w3c errors that i cannot fix

Tags: html, css

I have some code that seems to work on every browser that I test it on but I when I run it through the w3c validator, I get wierd errors. 2 of them are  tages that should not be there even though they have to be there and several un closed . Again if I take them out it stops the whole thing working. Like I said it works fine I just dont want errors.

The code is :

```
<div class="container">  
<div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:10px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
<div class="panel panel-info" >
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-title login-text hidden-xs">Login to your account</div>
<div class="panel-title login-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Login to your account</div>
</div>     

<div class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"></div>
<div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
<div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

<form method="post" class="login_check" action="process-login.php">
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
<input id="login-email" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter your email address">                                        
</div>



<div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
<input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Company account
</label>
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="send" value="Login">
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
</form>
<!-- Button -->
<div id = "login_status" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;">
  <strong>Sorry they dont match</strong></div>




<div class="col-md-12 control">

     <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').fadeIn('slow');$('#reminder_sent').hide();  ">
     <br>Forgot your password?
     </a>

</div>


</div>                    
</div>  
</div>
 <div id="signupbox" style="display:none; margin-top:10px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-title login-text hidden-xs">Forgot Password</div>
<div class="panel-title login-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Forgot Password</div>
</div>  
 <div class="panel-body" >

<form method="post" class="resend_password" action="resend_password.php">
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px" class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
<input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter your email address">                                        


</div>



<div class="form-group">

<!-- Button -->                                        

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="send" value="Send password">
</form>

</div>


<div id = "reminder_sent" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;">
  <strong>Your password reminder has been sent
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12 control">

<div style="border-top: 1px; solid#888; padding-top:20px; font-size:85%" ><span class="gotit">Got it?</span> 
<a href="#" onClick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show();$('#login_status').hide();">Login here</a></div>
</div>
</div>    

</div>
</div>             
</div> 
</div>
```

The errors I am getting are

Error
311 The "div" element must have an end tag () but the end tag was not found, is misplaced, or was not seen due to other errors.

Error
316 The end tag for "div" (started in line 311, column 2) should appear before the end tag for "form" or this end tag should be deleted or moved. This is a nesting error.



 Error
322 The "strong" element must have an end tag () but the end tag was not found, is misplaced, or was not seen due to other errors.
  Your password reminder has been sent


 Error
323 The end tag for "strong" (started in line 322, column 4) should appear before the end tag for "div" or this end tag should be deleted or moved. This is a nesting error.

CSS Error
328 Bad CSS declaration; cannot find the colon separating the property name from its value.

Got it? 


 Error
336 The end tag for "div" was found, but all "div" start tags already have end tags (or there is a nesting error). The next expected end tag is , which was started in line 194, column 2.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**) and **quote the error messages**. You also need to give a clear problem statement, "it stops the whole thing working" is incredibly vague.

Comment: Please show us the errors

Comment: ? WHat do you mean? Thats the code I am getting, do you want the error codes I am getting too?

Comment: @Jules — [mcve] is a link to an extended explanation.

Comment: Indent your code and we can have something to work with

Comment: Those don't sound like the typical error messages the W3C hosted validation service gives.

Comment: But again, read [mcve] and produce a *reduced* test case.

Comment: Because it works in browsers does not necessarily mean it will pass a validator. If you indent your html properly, you will most likely find where these/this div is misplaced/or missing

Comment: If you check in the end of this fiddle, you'll see the red marked tags that does not have a proper placed start tag, which answers your question: https://jsfiddle.net/b0p9frah/

Comment: I can 3 red markers, if I move the start tags I lose data its posting?

Comment: Yes, 3 tags ... so move end tags instead of start tags. This is what we can help with, the rest, to understand what and why, you really need to know if to make web pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `</div>` before the seceond `</form>` and remove one at the end.